# How to avoid changing object in cache before saving Spring Cache

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-data-jpa, spring-cache

I want to show right away with an example. There is such a repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

String USER_CACHE = "users";

@Override
@CachePut(value = USER_CACHE, key = "#user.email", unless = "#result == null")
<S extends User> S save(S user);

@Override
@CacheEvict(value = USER_CACHE, key = "#user.email")
void delete(User user);

@Cacheable(value = USER_CACHE, key = "#email", unless = "#result == null")
User findByEmailIgnoreCase(String email);

}
```

And there is such a service that saves the user's changes and sends a confirmation code to the mail:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService, UserDetailsService {

private final UserRepository userRepository;

@Override
public User getUserByEmail(String email) {
    return userRepository.findByEmailIgnoreCase(email);
}

@Override
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public void createAppUser(RegistrationAppRequestDto registrationRequest) throws EmailSendingException {
    User user = getUserByEmail(registrationRequest.getEmail());

    user.setPassword(registrationRequest.getPassword());
    user.setApp(true);
    user.setActivated(false);
    user.setActivationCode(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    user.setLastVisit(LocalDateTime.now());

    if (Strings.isEmpty(user.getImg())) {
        user.setImg(DEFAULT_IMG);
    }

    mailSender.sendWelcomeMessage(user);    
    userRepository.save(user);
 }
}
```

And the problem is that in case of an error (For example, when sending a message to the mail), the changes that were made with this user will remain in the cache, and these changes will not get into the database (which is correct). Is there any practice of working with such a case? Alternatively, i can use object cloning, but I think this is a bad practice. I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: If you are using JPA don't use Spring Cache, use the Caching integration for your JPA provider (probably Hibernate) which will manage all that for you. Which would be the best practice and would integrate better, if you really want to use Spring Cache (which I wouldn't recommend in this case) use a transaction aware cache manager that will align with the transaction.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks, I've looked at how the hibernate cache works and it really does look like a solution

Answer (score 0):

Using a JPA provider's cache, such as Hibernate's L2 cache, may be 1 solution, but now you have shifted the (configurable, conditional and optional) caching concern from the application to the persistence provider, which may not be desirable nor portable in all cases.

For instance, what happens when you are not using JPA and a database as the persistence provider/backing store, but another store like Cassandra as your system of record (SOR) to back certain services? Or, maybe you are making a call to a [REST-based] Web service (e.g. Google Maps/Geocoding API) from your application service class? What then?

1 of the problems you will encounter, especially if you are just using the ["Simple" caching provider](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/io.html#io.caching.provider.simple) provided by Spring [Boot] (also [described](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-store-configuration-jdk) in Spring Framework's Cache Abstraction documentation), is that the reference to the object returned by the cache is the actual object stored in the cache.

This is similar to:

```java
Map<String, User> users = new HashMap<>();

// populate Map, for example:
users.put("jonDoe", User.as("Jon Doe").active());

assertThat(users.get("jonDoe").isActive()).isTrue();

// then...
User jonDoe = users.get("jonDoe")

jonDoe.setActive(false);

assertThat(users.get("jonDoe").isActive()).isFalse();
```

Worse yet is the situation where the (changed) state of the object cached is part of the `equals` and `hashCode` methods (often used by caches when performing cache operations: `get(key)`, `put(key, value)`, etc), which would affect the mapping, and affect any `Map`-based cache implementation.

Most caching providers offer a setting, such as `copy-on-read` (semantics), when the cached value (object) is read from or stored to the cache. This is particularly useful in local-based caches (used in "*Near Caching*"), which can supplement a client/server based Cache (e.g. Redis) to decrease network hops on access, particularly for infrequently changing data.

If the caching solution is pure client/server (with no local caching, just proxying to the server from the client), which is most production topology arrangements (given cached data is usually "shared"), then the fear of modifying the cache is nil since the value accessed to/from the server (e.g. Redis) needs to be de/serialized anyway.

If you are using Spring Boot's "Simple" (`ConcurrentMap`-backed) `Cache` implementation, perhaps just for (profile-based) testing purposes, then you can even configure the "Simple" `Cache` to return copied values on read:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
class CustomCachingConfiguration {

  @Bean
  CacheManagerCustomizer cacheManagerCustomizer() {

    return cacheManager -> {
      if (cacheManager instanceof ConcurrentMapCacheManager concurrentMapCacheManager) {
        concurrentMapCacheManager.setStoreByValue(true);
      }
    };
  }
```

This configuration is specific to caching provider.

With Apache Geode (VMware GemFire), you would configure the cache using [`GemFireCache.copyOnRead(boolean)`](https://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/geode/cache/GemFireCache.html#setCopyOnRead-boolean-). Of course, in a non-local/non-embedded, proxy-only, client/server topology, this is not necessary.

With Hazelcast, especially in embedded capacity (a form of *Near Caching*), you would use [`CacheConfig.setStoreByValue(boolean)`](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/javadoc/com/hazelcast/config/AbstractCacheConfig.html#setStoreByValue-boolean-).

Again, many robust caching providers supported by Spring [Boot], that implement the *JCache* API and can function as a *JCache* caching provider as well (for which Spring and Spring Boot offer excellent [support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/io.html#io.caching.provider.jcache), and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-jsr-107)) offer similar configuration as well.

This should not affect any of your application code, only your configuration, and it should not be application tier (for example: persistence) dependent.